# How do I cultivate Samatha and Vipassana according to the Suttas?

Tags: practice

According to the Suttas, how do I practice Vipassana and how do practice samatha? Are these practices differentiated or not?

Comment: Asking six questions per day is maybe too many for this site. In the past it was once suggested that [the list of newest questions](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions) shouldn't be all from the same person.

Comment: See for example [this meta-post](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/171/254).

Comment: Who else will ask questions? This site is not exactly highly trafficked. Possibly the moderators here should drop their habitual non-Buddhist secular ideas and have more of a Buddhist bent. Keep in mind in Buddhism the student asking questions is the most essential thing. Its always problematic when aliens who have never lived in a Buddhist culture moderate a Buddhist forum on a website created by computer nerds/geeks.

Comment: One of my answers is here: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/17583/8157

Comment: Two of my answers are here: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/33264/8157 & https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/17583/8157

Comment: @DhammaDhatu It isn't to do with "who" is asking, but "what", "why", and "how much". If one person "floods" a site with questions that becomes a problem too (see previous experience with a couple of users I could name). Anyway part of a moderator's function on SE is to relay various site-specific policies which "the community" discussed on the Meta site.

Comment: The questions are good and often challenging, such as on MN 39 and MN 17. Credit where credit is due.